# SQL Syntax error while trying WSO2 CEP getting started sample

Tags: oracle, wso2, datasource, wso2-cep

Am new to W2 CEP and trying to run the samples given in the Wso2 CEP documentation. I was actually following the getting started guide and almost through with all the steps without any issues. But stuck with the last but one step while creating a personalized dash board.

Am using Oracle database as my datasource and I was able to refer the datasource created in CEP while creating the dashboard and the connection is validated successfully. But when I enter my sql "select * from delivered_orders" and upon running it gives me an error of "You have an error in your SQL syntax". In the console I can see a corresponding ORA error "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

The sql statement as you have seen is a very basic statement to have any syntax errors. Am not sure whats wrong with my setup, any help regarding this would be great.

I have read couple of other titles from stack overflow on this which suggest I should not use composite primary keys which was bug with WSO2 CEP. I tried that but still no good.

---

Additional Details : 0ct 3'rd

I tried the same sample with MySql and it works like a charm. And thanks for Colinr for the ticket, I see the documentation updated. But still I have issues while connecting with Oracle.

Comment: Check your local DBA for any VPD/RLS policies taking place on the `delivered_orders` table. That's the first thing which came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your command may be missing a terminator ';'
If that solves your issue, I'll try to get the document updated.

Comment: I tried it now am getting the same error on the browser. But the below error from the console, java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character. Thanks.

Comment: ok, it was worth a try!  I'll reproduce the issue and get back to you.

Comment: Sure Thank you. Some additional info, the oracle instance runs on a server not on my local desktop where I actually run my CEP. And also I use db admin credentials while connecting to the database. Please revert back for any other details required. Thanks.

Comment: I received a distinct error at the same step, when attempting this simple query, likely because I'm using mysql instead of oracle.  Nevertheless, there may be an issue with querying an empty table.  I was only able to successfully complete the sample after creating some dummy data in the table.  Perhaps the same may hold true for you.

Comment: FYI, I've opened a ticket to correct the documentation:  https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-1156

Comment: Thanks. I have some test data input to the table actually but still I have the same error. The only difference is am using oracle. I will also try this with MySQL at home but oracle is our enterprise database. So would be great if you could try the same with an oracle instance and see if you could reproduce it. Thanks again.